# Remove the last three characters from a string

Tags: c#, .net

I want to remove last three characters from a string:

```
string myString = "abcdxxx";
```

Note that the string is dynamic data.

Answer (score 326, accepted):

> read last 3 characters from string [Initially asked question]

You can use [string.Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and give it the starting index and it will get the substring starting from given index till end.

```
myString.Substring(myString.Length-3)
```

> Retrieves a substring from this instance. The substring starts at a
>   specified character position. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa904307%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

**Edit**, for updated post

> Remove last 3 characters from string [Updated question]

To remove the last three characters from the string you can use [string.Substring(Int32, Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx) and give it the starting index `0` and end index *three less than the string length*. It will get the substring before last three characters.

```
myString = myString.Substring(0, myString.Length-3);
```

[String.Substring Method (Int32, Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Retrieves a substring from this instance. The substring starts at a
>   specified character position and has a specified length.

You can also using [String.Remove(Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ad138yc(v=vs.110).aspx) method to remove the last three characters by passing start index as *length - 3*, it will remove from this point to end of string.

```
myString = myString.Remove(myString.Length-3)
```

[String.Remove Method (Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ad138yc(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Returns a new string in which all the characters in the current
>   instance, beginning at a specified position and continuing through the
>   last position, have been deleted

Comment: In C#8+, you can do this `myString[..^3]`

Answer (score 30):

```
myString = myString.Remove(myString.Length - 3, 3);
```

Comment: The documentation on String.Remove is confusing.  The lead sentence: "Returns a new string in which a specified number of characters from the current string are deleted."  This makes one think at first that `string.Remove(3)` would do the trick (or maybe remove three characters from the start of the string), but then on reading the overload descriptions one realises it doesn't.

Answer (score 19):

I read through all these, but wanted something a bit more elegant.  Just to remove a certain number of characters from the end of a string:

```
string.Concat("hello".Reverse().Skip(3).Reverse());
```

output:

```
"he"
```

Comment: This one is quite "creative", since it doesn't need the string's length, but the reverse operation is probably more expensive.

Comment: Reversing a string is definitely more expensive than counting its characters.  A whole new string needs to be constructed, then the original copied to it, then the original string needs to be garbage collected.

Comment: @MattGregory strings are immutable: Remove, Substring, any string function generates a new string. Overwriting the original pointer always causes garbage collection. This is still slower though, as `Enumerable.Reverse` buffers the string into a `char[]`, then buffers into a new `char[]` that's 3 shorter, and then generates a new `string` (with internally another `char[]`). A better approach would be `new string("hello".Reverse().Skip(3))`, or just writing your own string extension function `AllBut(this string in, int i)` that uses Substring.

Comment: @MattGregory It's not even "counting" a string's characters, a string has its `Length` stored.

Comment: Now we also have `.SkipLast(n)`. No need to reverse anything. `"hello".SkipLast(3)` gives `"he"`

Comment: Love it! I wanted a nice single line version. Since this part is node performance critical, I like the solution best.

Comment: This is without question the most unintuitive solution in the entire thread.

Comment: With all due respect, trying new things is fun, but this will give you the least performance. By calling reverse(), you are iterating through the string and generating brand new string. In the backend, this might seem very fast, but considering it's costing a O(N/2) time in the best case, and repeating this twice, and on top, skip & concat are still a cost but with O(1) time, they're still ignorable., So, most of the time, best solution is the simplest ones.

Comment: I regret this answer, and would not do this now.

Answer (score 19):

The new C# 8.0 range operator can be a great shortcut to achieve this.

Example #1 (to answer the question):

```
string myString = "abcdxxx";
var shortenedString = myString[0..^3]
System.Console.WriteLine(shortenedString);
// Results: abcd
```

Example #2 (to show you how awesome range operators are):

```
string s = "FooBar99";
// If the last 2 characters of the string are 99 then change to 98
s = s[^2..] == "99" ? s[0..^2] + "98" : s;
System.Console.WriteLine(s);
// Results: FooBar98
```

Answer (score 13):

```
myString.Remove(myString.Length-3);
```

Comment: `myString = myString.Remove(myString.Length - 3)` that is.

Answer (score 10):

If you're working in C# 8 or later, you can use "[ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges)":

```
string myString = "abcdxxx";
string trimmed = myString[..^3]; // "abcd"
```

More examples:

```
    string test = "0123456789", s;
    char c;
    c = test[^3]; // '7'
    s = test[0..^3]; // "0123456"
    s = test[..^3]; // "0123456"
    s = test[2..^3]; // "23456"
    s = test[2..7]; // "23456"
    //c = test[^12]; // IndexOutOfRangeException
    //s = test[8..^3]; // ArgumentOutOfRangeException
    s = test[7..^3]; // string.Empty
```

Answer (score 8):

```
string test = "abcdxxx";
test = test.Remove(test.Length - 3);
//output : abcd
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`String.Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ad138yc.aspx) to delete from a specified position to the end of the string.

```
myString = myString.Remove(myString.Length - 3);
```

Answer (score 6):

Probably not exactly what you're looking for since you say it's "dynamic data" but given your example string, this also works:

```
? "abcdxxx".TrimEnd('x');
"abc"
```

Answer (score 3):

`str= str.Remove(str.Length - 3);`

Answer (score 3):

Easy. `text = text.remove(text.length - 3)`.  I subtracted 3 because the `Remove` function removes all items from that index to the end of the string which is `text.length`. So if I subtract 3 then I get the string with 3 characters removed from it.

You can generalize this to removing `a` characters from the end of the string, like this:

```
text = text.remove(text.length - a)
```

So what I did was the same logic. The `remove` function removes all items from its inside to the end of the string which is the length of the text. So if I subtract `a` from the length of the string that will give me the string with `a` characters removed.

So it doesn't just work for 3, it works for all positive integers, except if the length of the string is less than or equal to `a`, in that case it will return a negative number or 0.

Answer (score 2):

```
myString.Substring(myString.Length - 3, 3)
```

Here are examples on substring.>>

http://www.dotnetperls.com/substring

Refer those.

Answer (score 2):

```
   string myString = "abcdxxx";
   if (myString.Length<3)
      return;
   string newString=myString.Remove(myString.Length - 3, 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the last characters from a string

```
TXTB_DateofReiumbursement.Text = (gvFinance.SelectedRow.FindControl("lblDate_of_Reimbursement") as Label).Text.Remove(10)
```

`.Text.Remove(10)`// used to remove text starting from index 10 to end

Answer (score 1):

```
items.Remove(items.Length - 3)
```

`string.Remove()` removes all items from that index to the end. `items.length - 3` gets the index 3 chars from the end

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic and ready to use method. It **takes char count to trim** from the end, uses C# 8.0 [Range operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#range-operator-) and checks for invalid input:

```cs
static string? TrimEnd(string? text, int charCount)
{
    if (text == null || text.Length <= charCount || charCount < 0)
    {
        return null;
    }
    return text[..^charCount];
}
```

Usage:

```cs
string myString = "abcdxxx";
string? result = TrimEnd(myString, 3);
// Here result is "abcd"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can call the Remove method and pass the last 3 characters

```
str.Substring(str.Length-3)
```

Complete code can be

```
str.Remove(str.Substring(str.Length-3));
```